# Adding months to datetime in PHP gives unexpected results

Tags: php, datetime

Our users can add their free times in a calender and they only need to mark 1 week of times. I have to create a for loop, to get all the users start and end-times and add 1 month (up to three months) so I could get the start and end times with increased months. So let's say the user added timestamp in database (currently only 1 for testing, but there can be many) is

```
startTime = 2018-02-28 08:00:00 - endtime = 2018-02-28 08:30:00
```

Then i would need to display the times like this:

```
2018-02-28 08:00:00 - 2018-02-28 08:30:00 
2018-03-28 08:00:00 - 2018-03-28 08:30:00 
2018-04-28 08:00:00 - 2018-04-28 08:30:00 
2018-05-28 08:00:00 - 2018-05-28 08:30:00
```

This is what I tried.

// get all the times

```
$times = Nanny_availability::where('user_id', user()->id)->get();

foreach($times as $time)
    {
    $start_times[] = new DateTime($time['start_time']);
    $end_times[] = new DateTime($time['end_time']);
    $available_times[] = $time['start_time'] . ' - ' . $time['end_time'];
    }

// add months

foreach($start_times as $start_time)
    {

    // add six months times interval

    for ($x = 0; $x <= 3; $x++)
        {
        $sixMonthsStart[] = $start_time->add(new DateInterval("P" . $x . "M"));
        }
    }

return Response::json($sixMonthsStart);
```

This is my json response.

```
[  
   {  
      "date":"2018-08-28 08:00:00.000000",
      "timezone_type":3,
      "timezone":"Europe/Helsinki"
   },
   {  
      "date":"2018-08-28 08:00:00.000000",
      "timezone_type":3,
      "timezone":"Europe/Helsinki"
   },
   {  
      "date":"2018-08-28 08:00:00.000000",
      "timezone_type":3,
      "timezone":"Europe/Helsinki"
   },
   {  
      "date":"2018-08-28 08:00:00.000000",
      "timezone_type":3,
      "timezone":"Europe/Helsinki"
   }
]
```

How can I add the months?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are modifying and assigning the same `$start_time` object in each iteration. The `add()` method does not return a new `DateTime` object.

Try this approach using the `clone` keyword to make a copy of the object:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 6; $x++)
{
    $date = clone $start_date;
    $dates[] = $date->modify("+$x months");
}
```

Comment: @dhinchliff If this how you write your code then I hope I don't ever have to maintain it

Comment: @avpav I don't generally work with rude people, so you don't need to worry

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `DateTimeImmutable`. From the php docs:

> This class behaves the same as DateTime except it never modifies itself but returns a new object instead.

Bascially every time you call `add` on a DateTime object you mutate your base object and on the next iteration of your `for` loop you no longer have the same date you started of with.
So you can either use `DateTimeImmutable` or increment month by `1` on every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Adding months can be achieved in this way:

```
$fmt = 'Y-m-d H:i:s'; // Date format

// Start with a timestamp, such as time() or strtotime($time['start_time'])
$t = time();
print(date($fmt, $t)."\n");

for ($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {

    // Feed the string datetime with a text instruction to strtotime()
    $t = strtotime(date($fmt, $t).' +1 Month');

    // Print resulting date, or store somewhere
    print(date($fmt, $t)."\n");
}
```

Output from this script when I ran it:

```
2018-03-26 03:17:58
2018-04-26 03:17:58
2018-05-26 03:17:58
```